# chapter style with tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

Is it possible to customize chapter style like below picture by using tcolorbox package? if not, can you show me which package could  generate that such style? Thanks[image]

Comment: we can ignore the background picture on the left handsite.

Comment: What have you got so far in terms of code? Note that without a minimal example document, any solution is likely to not work for your document because we just don't know anything about it. So the answer to you first question is 'Yes'. The bonus answer is: 'and show us what you've tried if you get stuck implementing it'.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's one possibility using [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). An image for an unnumbered chapter:

[image]

An image for a numbered chapter:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{titlebgdark}{RGB}{0,163,243}
\definecolor{titlebglight}{RGB}{191,233,251}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
      enhanced,
      colback=titlebgdark,
      boxrule=0.25cm,
      colframe=titlebglight,
      arc=0pt,
      outer arc=0pt,
      leftrule=0pt,
      rightrule=0pt,
      fontupper=\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\huge,
      enlarge left by=-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin, 
      enlarge right by=-\paperwidth+1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin+\textwidth,
      width=\paperwidth, 
      left=1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin, 
      right=\paperwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth,
      top=0.6cm, 
      bottom=0.6cm,
      overlay={
        \node[
          fill=titlebgdark,
          draw=titlebglight,
          line width=0.15cm,
          inner sep=0pt,
          text width=1.7cm,
          minimum height=1.7cm,
          align=center,
          font=\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont
        ] 
        (chapname)
        at ([xshift=-4cm]frame.north east)
        {\thechapter};
        \node[font=\small,anchor=south,inner sep=2pt] at (chapname.north)
        {\MakeUppercase\chaptertitlename};  % if using amsbook, this should be \chaptername
      } 
    ]
    #1
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  }
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
      enhanced,
      colback=titlebgdark,
      boxrule=0.25cm,
      colframe=titlebglight,
      arc=0pt,
      outer arc=0pt,
      remember as=title,
      leftrule=0pt,
      rightrule=0pt,
      fontupper=\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\huge,
      enlarge left by=-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin, 
      enlarge right by=-\paperwidth+1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin+\textwidth,
      width=\paperwidth, 
      left=1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin, 
      right=\paperwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth,
      top=0.6cm, 
      bottom=0.6cm, 
    ]
    #1
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{A test unnumbered chapter}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter{A test chapter with a long title that will span more than one line}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo. Is it possible to put the "chapter" on the top of small box (i.e. "1")

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaNguyễnVũ You're welcome. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Dear Gonzala, Can you tell me which code can adjust the the size of the small box (square rectangular) on the right top? and I also want to move the box to the right a little bit. How can adjust it. Pls forgive me, coz i am newbie of Tex.

Comment: Dear Gonzalo, you can refer to my question with the pic at http://imgur.com/9zBzJAV . If the chapter title too long so that it will close very much with the rectangular box. I would like to move it to the right a litter bit and make the number in box occupied all most the box. Many thanks for your instruction!

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaNguyễnVũ I can't reproduce the problem you mentioned. Move the number to the right changing the `-4cm`  in      `(chapname)
        at ([xshift=-4cm]frame.north east)
        {\thechapter};` to a smaller value (`-3cm` or whatever value suits your needs). For the other resuirement, change the values in `font=\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont` to a bigger font size, for example `font=\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont`.

Comment: For anyone trying to use this with amsbook, there is a small change needed to make it work right in the appendices: `\chaptertitlename` should be `\chaptername`. I added a comment in the code for this.