# using chapter style in latex

Tags: packages, chapters, package-writing, chapterthumb

I want to be like the output below. Please heip me! Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: Please tell us which document class you're using. In addition, please be more specific about the exact details you require. E.g., should the words in the argument of `\chapter` be rendered in uppercase, small-caps, bold, etc? How important is the drop shadow around the rectangle with rounded edges? What about the color to be used? What font sizes should be used? Please be as specific as you can be.

Answer (score 2):

Use `titlesec` and `tcolorbox`. Look at this solution: [chapter style with tcolorbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254318/chapter-style-with-tcolorbox) It uses a different box layout, but you can adapt the `tcolorbox` options to get your desired layout.

Here is an initial adaptation of that solution for numbered chapters:
You will need to tune it, by adapting the colors, dimensions and things like that.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
      enhanced,
      rounded corners,
      shadow={1mm}{-1mm}{-2.2mm}{black!20!white},
      colback=white,
      boxrule=0mm,
      arc=3mm,
      leftrule=0pt,
      rightrule=0pt,
      fontupper=\color{blueish}\sffamily\bfseries\huge,
      width=\textwidth-3.2mm,  % account for shadow width.
      top=0.6cm, 
      bottom=0.6cm,
      overlay={
        \node[
          fill=blueish,
          line width=0cm,
          inner sep=0pt,
          text width=13mm,
          minimum height=16mm,
          align=center,
          anchor=south east,
          xshift=2.2mm, yshift=9mm,
          font=\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont
        ] 
        (chapname) at (frame.north east) {\thechapter};
        \node[color=gray,font=\large,anchor=base east,inner sep=1mm] at (chapname.base west)
        {\chaptertitlename};  
      } 
    ]
    \MakeUppercase{#1}
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  }
```

This gives

[image]

Comment: This reads more like a comment than a full answer. At a minimum, you may want to suggest *which* `tcolorbox` options will need to be adapted.

Comment: Added some code. Should be adapted by the OP to get all the details right.